# Design the best schemes in terms of information transmission speed

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, coding-theory

Design a channel coding scheme to correct one error for the message source $$\{000, 100, 010, 001, 110, 101, 011, 111\}.$$ Can you find one of the best schemes in terms of information transmission speed?

I am trying to solve in different ways but not getting any confom way. Any help will be greatly appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: Before "trying to solve" a problem (and before posting it here) you should recognize if the problem does not make sense. This does not make sense. You cannot even start to find some "best" thing if you don't know the model and the performance measure. Which is the channel? How much redundancy you are allowed ? "best" according to what?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a code where the [Hamming distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_distance) between code words is $3$:

```
0:000000
1:100011
2:010111
3:110100
4:001110
5:101101
6:011001
7:111010
```

Note that the first three bits contain the encoded data word.

As all pairs of code words differ in three bit positions, a single bit error cannot change a code word into another one. The erroneous word can always be correctly related to the intended word.

I found this code using the following [MiniZinc](http://www.minizinc.org/) script:

```
%  code words
int: n = 8;
int: d = ceil(log2(n));

%  total bits
int: t = d + 3;

array[1..n, 1..t] of var bool: code;

function var int: hammingDistance(int: a, int: b) =
  sum([code[a, i] != code[b, i]| i in 1..t]);

constraint forall(i, j in 1..n where j > i) (
  3 <= hammingDistance(i, j)
);

constraint forall(i in 1..n) (
  (1*code[i, 1] + 2*code[i, 2] + 4*code[i, 3]) == (i-1)
);

solve satisfy;

output
[if j == 1 then "\n" ++ show(i) ++ ":" else "" endif ++ 
 if show(code[i,j]) == "true" then "1" else "0" endif | i in 1..n, j in 1..t] ++
["\n"];
```